# Capture output with shell parameter set to true

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I have an application running that requires it to be launched in it's own shell. I set the `shell` to `true` to achieve this, and it works. However, I am now unable to capture any stdout and send any stdin.

Is there any way to have the shell parameter enabled and still capture output and also send it?

```
var process_parameters = {

  maxBuffer: ( 1024 * 5000000 ),
  shell: true,
  detached: true

};

var process = child_process.spawn( application, parameters, process_parameters );

process.stdout.on( "data", function( content ) {

  //this never gets called
  console.log(content);

});
```

Comment: I think the syntax just needs to be `process.stdout.on('data'...)`. Note the `stdout.`. See here: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process

Comment: When I set the "shell" parameter to false it once again captures stdout just fine, even with the syntax it seems. Added it in my question nevertheless, maybe it makes a difference.